# How do I change HTML5 video playback speed (e.g., 1.5x, 2x) in Safari for Yosemite?

Tags: safari, video, macos, quicktime, html

I use ClickToFlash to switch most videos from Flash to HTML5 (QuickTime) versions in Safari.

HTML5 allows for variable speed playback, but not in the quicktime plugin for safari so far as I can tell. Any suggestions?

Looks like there's a Chrome extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/video-speed-controller/nffaoalbilbmmfgbnbgppjihopabppdk?hl=en

Comment: closest thing I"ve found so far is [Swift for iPhone](http://www.tapparatus.com/swift). Would like a safari extension though..

Comment: Youtube now has playback speed controls in their HTML5 player and on the iOS and Android apps. Playback Speed Controller extension for Chrome (link above) remains the fastest way to change the speed so far as I know. Swift for iPhone is no longer available (Apple banned it for allowing you to download YouTube videos).